# Is it possible to run spock specification from java code?

Tags: java, spock

I have written a spock specification. It works as expected when I run it as a junit test case. But I want to run it from java code not as junit testcase. Is there any way that I can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your reasoning for doing this? In general, unit tests should not need to be run outside of a unit test framework. If there is a reason to run it separately, then the best thing to do is to refactor so that your unit test and the thing you need to run are separated.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I understand that unit tests should not be run outside. But I want to call these tests only after completion of some functionality. I know this is weird , just wanted to know If this is possible.

Comment: I think you need to explore Maven/Gradle and a build server (e.g. Jenkins)